# Run OmniMarkupPreview's 'Export Markup as HTML' from Command Line?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

#### Question

Is there any way to run OmniMarkupPreviewer(Sublime Text's plugin)'s function, 'Export Markup as HTML' from command line?

https://github.com/timonwong/OmniMarkupPreviewer

#### Background

I am writing a [shell script](https://github.com/KENJU/git_shellscript) for pushing to Git. In the script, I want to achieve below requirements

- export README.markdown as HTML (I always do this by right-click in sublime window)
- rename automatically generated README_2015***.md to index.html (with mv command)
- then push origin to gh-pages branch ( so that github pages would be published)

#### So far

I found out that OmniMarkupPreviewer is written in Python, so what I am thinking is, if I can run the file for rendering/exporting markdown, maybe I can get the result what I want.

Therefore, I have looked upon below directory, but for I am beginner in python, I could not find out which file to run ( or maybe my approach would be completely wrong.)

> /Users/UserNameExample/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/OmniMarkupPreviewer

Would someone tell me how to run `Export Markup as HTML` command from shell script?

Comment: Why don't you just use original markdown translator? http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a python package for converting markdown to HTML, check out `markdown2`:
https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2

You can call it from the command line to convert your markdown file to html.
Only commands you need are to install it:

`pip install markdown2`

And then

`python markdown2.py foo.md > foo.html`

will convert `foo.md` to `foo.html`